# Help with Regex. Need to extract `<A HREF`

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i have `<A HREF="f110111.ZIP">` and `f110111` - is an arbitrary char sequence.
I need C# regex match expression to extract all above.

E. g. input is

`<A HREF="f110111.ZIP"><A HREF="qqq.ZIP"><A HREF="gygu.ZIP">`

I want the list:

- f110111.ZIP
- qqq.ZIP
- gygu.ZIP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the [htmlagility pack/](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)! That will allow you to read HTML in an easy manner and provide an easy way to retrieve links.

Comment: Why would you parse a complete html page when you exactly know what you want? It's a little bit overkill I think for this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you can have multiple dots in the filename:

```
<A HREF="(^["]+?).zip
```

If you do not have dots in the filename (just one before the `zip`), you can use a faster one:

```
<A HREF="(^[".]+)
```

C# example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<A HREF=\"(^[\"]+?).zip");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(buffer);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // do something with: matcher.group(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NO NO! [Do not use Regex to parse HTML!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Try an XML Parser. Or [XPath](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333) perhaps.

Comment: No No No. Parsing a full HTML document for this is **Crazy** with capital C.

Comment: @vbence: True enough :) But the OP did not specify how many links were there. Anyway, you would eventually get frustrated by trying to match all the possible scenario using RegEx.

Comment: I can think of situations where using Regular Expressions would be more robust than using a DOM tree (eg, if the links are not in uniform locations). This is exactly what Regex was built for. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @Mike Caron Although HTML is a basic tree structure. When you want to process it hierarchy-aware RegEx won't be much help. - This question does not seem to need it, that's why I vouch for RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/<a href="([^">]+.ZIP)/gi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Regular Expressions are a great way to filter text out of a given text.

This regex gets the File, Filename and Extension from the given text.

```
href="(?<File>(?<Filename>.*?)(?<Ext>\.\w{1,3}))"
```

Regex above expects an extension that exists out of word characters a-z A-Z 0-9, between 1 and 3 characters.

C# Code sample:

```
string regex = "href=\"(?<File>(?<Filename>.*?)(?<Ext>\\.\\w{1,3}))\"";
RegexOptions options = ((RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline) | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex reg = new Regex(regex, options);
```